# Reading Text From File Into Variables

Tags: java

I've got a text file formatted like this:

```
 2 
 d e 
 2 
 1 0 e 
 0 1 d
```

I'd like to have a variable called size, which is equal to the first number, 4.  I also need a variable, num, to hold the third line (3).  I want to read the second line, d e, into an array.  I would also like to read the last two lines into two arrays - one for chars, and the other for ints.  I'll list my variables down here so it's easier to read:

```
size = 2   ---> first line
char[] chars = {d, e} ---> second line
num = 2  ---> third line
int[] pos = {1, 0, 0, 1} ---> Lines 4, 5
char[] posLetters = {e, d}  ---> Lines 4, 5
```

I'm not really sure how to declare the size of each of these arrays before reading the text in the file.  It's tricky because another text file could read:

```
3
a b c
4
0 3 b
2 0 c
1 2 a
0 2 b
```

The variables from this second file would be:

```
size = 3   ---> first line
char[] chars = {a, b, c} ---> second line
num = 4  ---> third line
int[] pos = {0, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2} ---> Lines 4, 5, 6, 7
char[] posLetters = {b, c, a, b}  ---> Lines 4, 5, 6, 7
```

This is the fourth or fifth draft of my code.  I've run into a wall.  I know how to print out the file line by line, but I don't know how to do it variable by variable.

```
try {
         File configFile = new File(config + "config.txt");
         Scanner configScanner = new Scanner(configFile);

         int size = configScanner.nextInt(); 



         int num = configScanner.nextInt(); 


        /*  
          int[][] board = new int[size][size];
          for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i ++) {
              for(int j = 0; j < size-1; j++) {
                  board[i][j] = 
configScanner.nextInt();
              }
          }
         */

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          // handle the exception here
          System.err.println(e);
          e.printStackTrace();
        } // try
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at LatinSqauresGame.printWelcome(LatinSqauresGame.java:59)
at LatinSqauresGame.<init>(LatinSqauresGame.java:13)
at LatinSquaresDriver.main(LatinSquaresDriver.java:6)
```

I want to have the results listed in the beginning:

```
size = 2   ---> first line
char[] chars = {d, e} ---> second line
num = 2  ---> third line
int[] pos = {1, 0, 0, 1} ---> Lines 4, 5
char[] posLetters = {e, d}  ---> Lines 4, 5
```

---

**EDIT:** Here's the code I have now:

```
  int size = variableScan.nextInt();
          char[] chars = new char[size];
          for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
              chars[i] = variableScan.next().charAt(0);
          }
          // Read pos and posLetters arrays
          int num = variableScan.nextInt();
          // code here to allocate and read pos and posLetters

          System.out.println(size);

          for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
             System.out.println(chars[i]);

          System.out.println(num);

          int iter = 0;
          while(variableScan.hasNextLine()) {

            int[] pos = new int[num*2];
            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                pos[i + (2*iter)] = variableScan.nextInt();
            }

            char[] posLetters = new char[num];
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                posLetters[i + iter] = variableScan.next().charAt(0);
            }

            iter++;

          }
```

paired with this text file:

```
2 
a b 
2 
0 0 a 
1 0 b
```

I get the output:

```
2
a
b
2
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at LatinSqauresGame.printWelcome(LatinSqauresGame.java:77)
    at LatinSqauresGame.<init>(LatinSqauresGame.java:13)
    at LatinSquaresDriver.main(LatinSquaresDriver.java:6)
```

Comment: Why are you using `hasNextLine()`? You're being told exactly how many lines you need to read (`num`). --- Also, don't you think it would be a good idea to declare and allocate the arrays *outside* the loop?

Answer (score 1):

You start by calling `nextInt()` **twice**, but your file only starts with one number, so of course it'll fail in the second `nextInt()` call.

Your code should start out like this:

```
// Read chars array
int size = configScanner.nextInt();
char[] chars = new char[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    chars[i] = configScanner.next().charAt(0);

// Read pos and posLetters arrays
int num = configScanner.nextInt();
// code here to allocate and read pos and posLetters
```

Comment: Okay.  That makes sense.  How do I add the last lines to separate arrays though?  I keep getting a no such element error.  I'll edit my post to include current code.